# Derived table error / object contains restricted characters

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to use a derived table for the first time and am getting an error message that says "SELECT failed 6725 Object name contains restricted characters.  I'm not sure what is wrong.  I've included the SQL below.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank You.

```
WITH drvd_amts (acct_nbr, grp_br_ps_org_id, PSAmt)
AS
(SELECT 
d.acct_nbr,
d.grp_br_ps_org_id,
sum(d.pstd_ttl_amt) as PSAmt

FROM psfs.ps_gl_acct_ldgr d
WHERE d.fiscal_yr_mth_nbr BETWEEN 201500 AND 201508
AND d.acct_nbr BETWEEN 150000 AND 160500

GROUP BY d.grp_br_ps_org_id, d.acct_nbr)

SELECT
a.FA_ACCT,
a.ERACBR,
a.deptid,
a.FA_AMT,
da.PSAmt,

CASE WHEN da.PSAmt IS NULL THEN a.FA_AMT
ELSE a.FA_AMT - da.PSAmt END AS DIFF

FROM 

(SELECT 
    pdr.account_fa AS FA_ACCT,
    ir.erac_branch_lgcy_cd AS ERACBR,
    pdr.deptid,
    SUM(pdr.COST) AS FA_Amt

FROM PSFS.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 

LEFT JOIN INTGRT_RPT.DIM_LOCATION ir ON pdr.deptid = ir.erac_branch_ps_org_cd AND ir.curr_lrd_row_flg = 1

INNER JOIN RFS.STN_OPS_HIERARCHIES soh ON pdr.deptid = soh.department

WHERE pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0465'
AND pdr.BOOK = 'PERFORM'
AND pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015
AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 8
AND pdr.GROUP_ASSET_FLAG <> 'M'

GROUP BY FA_ACCT, ERACBR, deptid

UNION All

SELECT
pdr.account_ad AS FA_ACCT,
ir.erac_branch_lgcy_cd AS ERACBR,
pdr.deptid,
SUM(pdr.depr_ltd) AS FA_Amt

FROM PSFS.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 

LEFT JOIN INTGRT_RPT.DIM_LOCATION ir ON pdr.deptid = ir.erac_branch_ps_org_cd AND ir.curr_lrd_row_flg = 1

INNER JOIN RFS.STN_OPS_HIERARCHIES soh ON pdr.deptid = soh.department

WHERE pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0465'
AND pdr.BOOK = 'PERFORM'
AND pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015
AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD =8
AND pdr.GROUP_ASSET_FLAG <> 'M'

GROUP BY FA_ACCT, ERACBR, deptid ) a

LEFT JOIN drvd_amts da ON a.deptid = da.grp_br_ps_org_id
 AND a.fa_acct = da.acct_nbr

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6

HAVING DIFF <> 0

UNION

SELECT 
daq.acct_nbr AS FA_ACCT,
ir.erac_branch_lgcy_cd AS ERACBR,
daq.grp_br_ps_org_id,
b.FA_AMT,
daq.PSAmt,

CASE WHEN b.fa_amt IS NULL THEN daq.psamt
    ELSE b.FA_AMT – daq.psamt END AS DIFF

FROM drvd_amts daq

LEFT JOIN INTGRT_RPT.DIM_LOCATION ir ON daq.grp_br_ps_org_id = ir.erac_branch_ps_org_cd AND ir.curr_lrd_row_flg = 1 

LEFT  JOIN 

    (SELECT 
        pdr.account_fa AS FA_ACCT,
        pdr.deptid,
        SUM(pdr.COST) AS FA_Amt

    FROM PSFS.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 

    INNER JOIN RFS.STN_OPS_HIERARCHIES soh ON pdr.deptid = soh.department

    WHERE pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0465'
    AND pdr.BOOK = 'PERFORM'
    AND pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015
    AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 8
    AND pdr.GROUP_ASSET_FLAG <> 'M'

    GROUP BY FA_ACCT, deptid

UNION All

    SELECT
    pdr.account_ad AS FA_ACCT,
    pdr.deptid,
    SUM(pdr.depr_ltd) AS FA_Amt

    FROM PSFS.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 

    INNER JOIN RFS.STN_OPS_HIERARCHIES soh ON pdr.deptid =  soh.department

    WHERE pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0465'
    AND pdr.BOOK = 'PERFORM'
    AND pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015
    AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 8
    AND pdr.GROUP_ASSET_FLAG <> 'M'

    GROUP BY FA_ACCT, deptid) b

ON daq.grp_br_ps_org_id = b.deptid
AND daq.acct_nbr = b.fa_acct

Where ir.ody_group_cd = 'A0465'

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6

HAVING DIFF <> 0

ORDER BY 1, 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how you typed it (did you write the code in MS Word?), but in line 85 there's an illegal character:

```
ELSE b.FA_AMT – daq.psamt END AS DIFF
```

The '-' is not `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS` but `U+2013 EN DASH`, simply replace it.

Comment: @dnoeth.....Thanks but that is a formula where I am subtracting one amount from another.

Comment: @Shaves: Replace that single character, the `–` with a `-`. Depending on the font it might look the same, but it's not.

Comment: @dnoeth.......Thanks for your help.  That did the trick.  I'm not sure how I did that.  I use SQL Assistant to write code.  I spent an hour yesterday looking at all of the column names and aliases to make sure I hadn't typed something wrong.  I really appreciate your help.  Have a great day....